# import in a.py affects module lookup in b.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto

Here's a test example involving boto (although I don't think this is boto specific).   First create a simple python file:

```
echo "import boto; print boto.ec2.RegionData" > bad.py
```

Then if you try to import this module, you get an error:

```
python -c "import bad"
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ec2'
```

This is expected, since bad.py forgot to "import boto.ec2".  However, if you "import boto.ec2" just before "import bad", it works, surprisingly:

```
python -c "import boto.ec2; import bad"
```

**What's going on here?**  My understanding was that imports from one file only populate the namespace of that file, but this must be wrong.

Versions:

- python 2.7
- boto 2.13.3

BTW, I was able to reproduce this with my own dummy version of boto, that was basically just blank files, so I don't think this is a boto specific issue.

Comment: because you have imported `boto.ec2` into the  namespace

Comment: But if you "print sys.path" in bad.py, and then "import sys; import bad", that doesn't work.  So there's something more involved going on.

Comment: That is not the same thing, try `echo "import tkinter;print(tkinter.messagebox)" > bad.py` and you will get the exact same behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing a module in one file won't load it into other file's namespaces - but `import boto` and `import boto.ec2` both only add the `boto` package to the current namespace. The difference is that `import boto.ec2` also loads the `ec2` submodule of the `boto` package and assigns it to the `ec2` variable in **`boto`**'s namespace. Since every module that imports `boto` shares the same `boto` package, they all see this new addition.